# Network Administrating Software (Similar to ClearOS)

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, administration

I am looking for a network administrating software that is similar to the ClearOS in this link: http://www.clearfoundation.com/Software/screenshots.html

Of course the software should be for Ubuntu or work in Ubuntu but offer similar features as the administrative panels in ClearOS.

Is there a network administrative software similar to this in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webmin is very nice http://webmin.com/demo.html

webmin wiki http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin

you can add third-party modules too

Comment: Server down for the Live Test ^^. But reading the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you http://www.zentyal.com/

Comment: That is a nice alternative Engels but I am looking for a Ubuntu compatible package that offers similar characteristics. An Ubuntu network administrative solution to say it in less words.